# Incorrect plugin configuration Genesis state can only be set on a fresh blockchain

Tags: nodeos

I keep having this problem when starting nodeos. Anyone know how to fix it?

"Incorrect plugin configuration
Genesis state can only be set on a fresh blockchain."

This is the command I use

bin/nodeos --replay --data-dir /wallet/data --genesis-json /wallet/data/genesis.json --config-dir /wallet/data "$@" > /wallet/data/stdout.txt 2> /wallet/data/stderr.txt &

- directory structure is slightly modified

Comment: as the error says: don't use `-genesis-json /wallet/data/genesis.json` on a blockchain that already has data (`--data-dir /wallet/data `)